# Pass variables into and out of exec [closed for not being clear. Modified and reuploaded]

Tags: python

Given the following code

```
a = 100
b = 200

snip = '''
c = a+b
'''

exec(snip)
print(c)
```

how can I pass values into exec, and get values out of exec, without using global scope? In effect, I want to be able to explicitly control the entire scope `exec` has access to.

Comment: Note, in this case, the global `c` was modified, and you can see the effects of that by just doing `print(c)` again after `exec(snip)`

Comment: What is your question??? The code above works and prints 102 and even adding another `print(c)` after the `exec` also prints 102. So... What is your problem/question?

Comment: I updated the question to be a bit more clear

Answer (score 1):

Generally, global scope is used with exec

```
a = 100
b = 200

snip = '''
c = a+b
'''

exec(snip)
print(c)
```

However, this can be problematic in some use cases. `exec` allows you to pass in a dictionary defining the global scope, and receive a dictionary containing the local scope. Here's an example:

```
snip = '''
c = a+b
'''

input_globals = {'a': 100, 'b': 2}
output_locals = {}

exec(snip, input_globals, output_locals)
print(output_locals)
```

This results in the following output:

```
{'c': 102}
```

this effectively allows one to use exec "functionally", without working on and modifying global scope.

You can read [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/exec) for more detail.

Comment: "The dict loc is passed by reference" no it is not, nothing is *ever* passed by reference in Python.

Comment: TIL pass-by-reference vs pass-by-assignment. Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: I'll have to look into passed by assignment. I updated it to passed by assignment

Comment: Great answer here that enlightened me! https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/3280538

Comment: I don't understand the point of this (question and) answer... `gloabsl()` is already the default. The same works by just doing `exec(snip)` and then `print(c)`

Comment: Totally. I updated the question, and thus the answer, to be a bit more clear. Thanks for the feedback